# getting max value of a lambda and its key in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, max

Let's say I have

```
a = [11,2,5,-3]
```

I want to apply a lambda (**1/i** for each **i in a**) and I want to get an output as: **i, max(1/i)**

```
output: 2, 0.5
```

How can I achieve it in **one line** of code where calling **max** only once?

I can get like below, but it calls the **max** function twice.

```
max(a, key = lambda i : 1/i), max([1/i  for i in a])
```

Comment: is this an assignment ? stack overflow is not a place to post your homework

Comment: definitely not! I am curious, and not a student.

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite Not entirely true. We don't mind homework questions so long as all the criteria for asking a question here have been met

Comment: write `1./i`, otherwise you get integer division.

Comment: @ViG only true for python 2

Comment: @DavidG of course you **can** ask homework questions but the point of homework is to do it yourself, you have a teacher that should be the one answering any question...

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite There is discussion: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/5358968)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you already know `key` can be used with max, so you just need to create the tuple pairs in advance then use `max` with `key` on the pair, something like this:

```
max([(i,1/i) for i in a],key = lambda x: x[1])
```

or as mentioned you can use tuple comparison:

```
max((1/i, i) for i in a)
```

Comment: Or without `lambda`: `max_, val = max((1/i, i) for i in a)`

Comment: great answer @tobias_k